# Как добавить вычисляемое поле к модели поиска Yii2

Tags: yii2, activerecord, gridview

Имеются 2 таблицы в БД: categories и products.
Таблицы связаны один ко многим categories.id <=> products.category_id.
В модели Active Record описаны связи

```
class Category ... {
...
public function getProducts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Product::className(), ['category_id' => 'id']);
}

public function getProductsCount()
{
    return $this->getProducts()->count();
}
...
}

class Product ... {
...
public function getCategory()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Category::className(), ['id' => 'category_id']);
}
...
}
```

Хочу на странице категории вывести в GridView название категории и кол-во продуктов в ней, чтобы сохранилась возможность поиска и фильтрации по гриду.
Если просто вызвать productsCount в гриде, то нет возможности фильтровать.
Пробовал добавлять в модель поиска это и вызывать, но не понял как прописать фильтрацию и сортировку, если поле вычисляемое.

```
class Category extends CategoryModel
{
    public $productsCount;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ...
            [['productsCount'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Неужели это нельзя реализовать через модель поиска категорий и придется создавать отдельную модель?

Comment: https://yiiframework.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?t=34992